# What is the best way to get Python auto-completions/intellisense in Vim dynamically?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete

I have looked at `pydiction`, `pysmell` and `vim-ipython`. Both `pydiction` and `pysmell` require generating the index before we can use it, and `vim-ipython` requires loading back and forth before the autocompletion works. However, none of them give the on-the-fly auto-completion working in different `virtualenv`, like what `Aptana` can do.

Would an experienced Python-vimmer let us know please?

Comment: hey, I'm the author of vim-ipython, and I'm not sure what you mean by "`vim-ipython` requires loading back and forth before the autocompletion works" - can you clarify? Is the problem you're trying to solve effectively introspecting inside of different disjoint virtualenvs to be able to see only completions relevant to a particular env?

Comment: Hello @PaulIvanov thanks for your comment and your work on `vim-ipython`, which I found very useful (and I am using it for most of the time). Just that, every time I have to open a session of ipython before using the autocompletion of vim is not very friendly. Is there anyway to automate the initialization of the ipython session and connect that to vim automatically, whenever I open a *.py file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this: https://github.com/klen/python-mode

Dynamic omnicompletion from Rope and many other features.

Comment: Are you a genius? This is awesome. :-)

Comment: hi @klen, I have been using this `python-mode` for quite a while now. Everything is going well but I sometimes got an End Of Line problem when this python-mode is turned on. I can't seem to move the cursor (e.g. by pressing A) to the end of line (always 1 character off)... Have you had this experience before? Do you know how I may solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I dont see your comments. And I havent a problems with End Of Line.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) it's an ultimate completion system for vim.
For python it uses internal vim's python omni-completion which is pretty good doing it's job.

You should give it a try.

Comment: I would like the auto-completion to work with any other libraries without additional configuration. Vim's python omni-completion only restricts to python standard library.